# Custom Provider with React Router causes infinite render loop in React 18

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router, react-context

I've been facing a nasty bug with React Router (6.4.1) and our own custom provider after moving to React 18.

I have used an implementation inspired by this post - https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-conditionally-render-react-ui-based-on-user-permissions-7b9a1c73ffe2.

A brief design looks something like this -

[image]

This setup worked just fine with React 17. However, after moving to React 18. The Provider (and resulting the component that utilizes the provider causes an infinite render loop when a component state is updated elsewhere.

https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-fog-ck0xq4?file=/src/index.tsx this is the sandbox solution.

The re-render issue is so bad that it won't just load in editor mode. You have to go the preview mode of this app - https://ck0xq4.csb.app/page/12324 URL (preview mode) and click on the toggle button and observe teh Console logs.

**ADVICE - Because of the infinite render, the codesandbox may crash your browser / tab. Apologies in advance for that**

The moment it re-renders the conditional elements, the app goes in render loop.

I tried pinpointing the exact issue, I figured out that whenever I use `useParams` from `react-router-dom`, the Provider goes into an infinite loop.

There is a chance that the provider I have configured is completely wrong but I just cant get a hang of it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Relevant code:

index.tsx

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import * as ReactDOMClient from "react-dom/client";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import SubPage from "./SubPage";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOMClient.createRoot(rootElement);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "page/:pageId",
        element: <SubPage />
      }
    ]
  }
]);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

App.tsx

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import ActionProvider from "./providers/PermissionsProvider";
import "./styles.css";

export type Action = string;
export type UserActions = {
  groupId: string;
  roleName: string;
  actions: Action[];
};
export default function App() {
  const workspaceActions: UserActions = {
    groupId: "072f9aa7-1268-4b44-9f62-70cb43c38a59",
    roleName: "Privileged Member",
    actions: [
      "data.list",
      "data.read",
      "data.download",
      "data.archive",
      "data.create",
      "data.delete",
      "data.upload"
    ]
  };
  const fetchAvailableActions = () => (action: string) => {
    const permissions = workspaceActions.actions;
    return permissions.includes(action);
  };

  const [toggleMenu, setToggleMenu] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <ActionProvider fetchActions={fetchAvailableActions()}>
        {toggleMenu ? <div>sidebar</div> : <div>navbar</div>}
        <div className="App">
          <Outlet />
        </div>
      </ActionProvider>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setToggleMenu(!toggleMenu);
        }}
        type="button"
      >
        toggle
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

SubPage.tsx

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Restricted from "./providers/Restricted";

const SubPage = () => {
  const { pageId } = useParams();
  return (
    <Restricted to="data.list">
      <p>Hello from the subpage {pageId}</p>
      <p>
        Open Developer Toolbar (F12), navigate to console. Click on toggle
        button to replicate the issue. Observe the console logs.
      </p>
      <h1>
        Please be aware that the browser may crash because of the issue I
        explained. Advice is to open a separate browser instance which can be
        closed easily.
      </h1>
    </Restricted>
  );
};

export default SubPage;
```

ActionContext.ts

```
import React from "react";
import { Action } from "../models/providers/Permissions";

type ActionContextType = {
  isAllowedTo: (action: Action) => Promise<boolean>;
};

// Default behaviour for the Permission Provider Context
// i.e. if for whatever reason the consumer is used outside of a provider.
// The permission will not be granted unless a provider says otherwise
const defaultBehaviour: ActionContextType = {
  isAllowedTo: () => Promise.resolve(false)
};

// Create the context
const ActionContext = React.createContext<ActionContextType>(defaultBehaviour);

export default ActionContext;
```

PermissionsProvider.tsx

```
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from "react";
import { Action } from "../models/providers/Permissions";
import ActionContext from "./ActionContext";

type Props = {
  fetchActions: (p: Action) => boolean;
};

type ActionCache = {
  [key: string]: boolean;
};

// This provider is intended to be surrounding the whole application.
// It should receive the users permissions as parameter
const ActionProvider: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<Props>> = ({
  fetchActions,
  children
}) => {
  console.log("in action provider");
  const cache: ActionCache = {};

  // Creates a method that returns whether the requested permission is available in the list of permissions
  // passed as parameter
  const isAllowedTo = async (action: Action): Promise<boolean> => {
    console.log("isAllowedTo");
    if (Object.keys(cache).includes(action)) {
      return cache[action];
    }
    const isAllowed = await fetchActions(action);
    cache[action] = isAllowed;
    return isAllowed;
  };

  // This component will render its children wrapped around a PermissionContext's provider whose
  // value is set to the method defined above
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-constructed-context-values
  return (
    <ActionContext.Provider value={{ isAllowedTo }}>
      {children}
    </ActionContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ActionProvider;
```

Restricted.tsx

```
/* eslint-disable react/require-default-props */
/* eslint-disable react/jsx-no-useless-fragment */
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from "react";
import { Action } from "../models/providers/Permissions";
import usePermission from "./usePermission";

type Props = {
  to: Action;
  fallback?: JSX.Element | string;
};

// This component is meant to be used everywhere a restriction based on user permission is needed
const Restricted: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<Props>> = ({
  to,
  fallback,
  children
}) => {
  console.log("in restricted");
  // We "connect" to the provider thanks to the PermissionContext
  const allowed = usePermission(to);

  // If the user has that permission, render the children
  if (allowed) {
    return <>{children}</>;
  }

  // Otherwise, render the fallback
  return <>{fallback}</>;
};

export default Restricted;
```

usePermission.ts

```
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { Action } from "../models/providers/Permissions";
import ActionContext from "./ActionContext";

const useAction = (action: Action) => {
  const [allowed, setAllowed] = useState<boolean>();

  const { isAllowedTo } = useContext(ActionContext);

  isAllowedTo(action).then((_allowed) => {
    setAllowed(_allowed);
  });
  return allowed || false;
};

export default useAction;
```

Comment: your preview broke my browser

Comment: @Javito sorry for that. I have added the disclaimer now. On a bright side, now, you know the problem I am facing ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue I see in the code is with the `usePermission`/`useAction` hook, it is unconditionally enqueueing state updates. `isAllowedTo` is unconditionally called each render cycle as an unintentional side-effect and enqueues a state update which triggers another render cycle.

usePermission

```
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { Action } from "../models/providers/Permissions";
import ActionContext from "./ActionContext";

const useAction = (action: Action) => {
  const [allowed, setAllowed] = useState<boolean>();

  const { isAllowedTo } = useContext(ActionContext);

  isAllowedTo(action).then((_allowed) => { // <-- unintentional side-effect
    setAllowed(_allowed);                  // <-- update triggers rerender
  });

  return allowed || false;
};

export default useAction;
```

TBH I don't see how this ***wasn't*** an issue in `react@17`.

## Solution

Move the unintentional side-effect into a `useEffect` hook so it is an *intentional* side-effect.

Example:

```
const useAction = (action: Action) => {
  const [allowed, setAllowed] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const { isAllowedTo } = useContext(ActionContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    isAllowedTo(action).then((_allowed) => {
      setAllowed(_allowed);
    });
  }, [action]);

  return allowed;
};
```

Any eslinters with the React hooks enabled by complain about a missing `isAllowedTo` dependency, so to resolve this you'll likely want to provide a stable `isAllowedTo` callback reference.

PermissionsProvider

```
const ActionProvider: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<Props>> = ({
  fetchActions,
  children
}) => {
  console.log("in action provider");
  const cache: ActionCache = {};

  // Creates a method that returns whether the requested permission is available in the list of permissions
  // passed as parameter
  const isAllowedTo = useCallback(async (action: Action): Promise<boolean> => {
    console.log("isAllowedTo");
    if (Object.keys(cache).includes(action)) {
      return cache[action];
    }
    const isAllowed = await fetchActions(action);
    cache[action] = isAllowed;
    return isAllowed;
  }, [cache, fetchActions]);

  // This component will render its children wrapped around a PermissionContext's provider whose
  // value is set to the method defined above
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-constructed-context-values
  return (
    <ActionContext.Provider value={{ isAllowedTo }}>
      {children}
    </ActionContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

`isAllowedTo` can now be added to the dependency array.

```
const useAction = (action: Action) => {
  const [allowed, setAllowed] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const { isAllowedTo } = useContext(ActionContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    isAllowedTo(action).then((_allowed) => {
      setAllowed(_allowed);
    });
  }, [action, isAllowedTo]);

  return allowed;
};
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Very well explained. I am wondering why my code did work on React 17. A question to react github probably. Thanks again!